# NumPy - creating 1-hot tensor from a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have a numpy 2D array with values that range from 0 to 59.

for those who are familiar with DL and specifically Image Segmentation - I create the array (call it L) from a .png image and the value of each pixel L[x,y] means the class that this pixel belongs to (out of the 60 classes).

I want to create a 1-hot tensor - Lhot, in which (Lhot[x,y,z] == 1) only if (L[x,y] == z), and 0 otherwise.

I want to create it with some kind of broadcasting/indexing (1,2 lines) - without loops.

it should be functionally equal to this piece of code (Dtype corresponds to L):

```
Lhot = np.zeros((L.shape[0], L.shape[1], 60), dtype=Dtype)
for i in range(L.shape[0]):
    for j in range(L.shape[1]):
        Lhot[i,j,L[i,j]] = 1
```

anyone has an idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much faster and cleaner way using pure `numpy`

```
Lhot = np.transpose(np.eye(60)[L], (1,2,0))
```

Problem you'll run into with multidimensional one-hots is they get *really* big and *really* sparse and there's no good way to handle sparse arrays with more than 2D in `numpy`/`scipy` (or `sklearn` or many other ML packages either I think).  Do you really need an n-d one-hot?

Comment: I'm doing it to create an LMDB file for the labels in FCN-8s network for image segmentation (which was trained using the PASCAL-VOC 2012 dataset). the final softmax layer expects 2 arguments - the network score and these labels, and I saw that the score dimensions are {width,height,numClasses} , which made me think that it has to be a 1-hot representation and that I have to build the labels in the same way

Answer (score 3):

Since typical one-hot encoding is defined for 1D vectors, all you have to do is flatten your matrix, use one hot encoder from scikit-learn (or any other library with one-hot encoding) and reshape back.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
n, m = L.shape
k = 60
Lhot = np.array(OneHotEncoder(n_values=k).fit_transform(L.reshape(-1,1)).todense()).reshape(n, m, k)
```

of course you can do it by hand too

```
n, m = L.shape
k = 60
Lhot = np.zeros((n*m, k)) # empty, flat array
Lhot[np.arange(n*m), L.flatten()] = 1 # one-hot encoding for 1D
Lhot = Lhot.reshape(n, m, k) # reshaping back to 3D tensor
```

Comment: thank you, I'm running it now but it takes quite a while because I have many images (labels) that I need to run it for

Comment: the question is do you really need it. You might also just make the rest of your system (neural network I suppose) accept id rather than one-hot data. Expressing ont-hot processing as part of your network will save you a lot of RAM/time too.

Comment: you're right but I'm running it with a pre-defined net on caffe and it seems that the 3d softmax there expects the labels to be 1-hot representation, to comply with the score blob's dimensions